# BB10 generate bar file vs momentics workspace

Tags: blackberry, operating-system

I am clicking on my project, then clicking export.After clicking export i choose blackberry -> release build.
After this step i click next again, until i reach last step. I select enable digital signing and click on finish.
It starts exporting release build , but i get an error Error: Server cannot handle your request at the moment, please try again later.
 (Time of error: 18 August 2014 13:37:29 EES

what is this problem?

Comment: I have the same as you :(

Comment: its back now you can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signing server is down at the moment, just wait for some time
https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Signing-Server-down-again/m-p/2960188#M66552

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have checked :
 - IP : not wrong
 - Password : not wrong
 - All Setting already right
 But i just got that error..
Having go through BB Forum + This(StackOverflow) -> all people got this problem